# Testing URLs in a bash script on Mac OS X

Tags: bash

I'm very new to scripts, but nevertheless I would like to do the following:

I have a text file with a bunch of URLs, one per line. I want a bash script that opens each URL with a web browser, waits 5 seconds, gets the response from the page, then closes the browser and logs the response from the page caret separated after the URL in the text doc and repeats the process for each line.

Comment: The response is going to be many lines, in general.  Your output format is not well defined, therefore.

Comment: It's actually only the web service response, so it can all go on one line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the URL response, opening a GUI web browser isn't necessary. If so, then use `curl`:

```
for url in `cat urlList.txt`; do
    curl $url >> urlsOut.txt;
    echo "" >> urlsOut.txt;
    echo "^" >> urlsOut.txt;
done
```

If you want the parsed contents, i.e. something like the output in a browser window, you'll need to leverage something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), and this will be more than a bash solution.

Comment: I'm actually trying to make a web service POST call. So I don't believe curl will work.

Comment: if you're doing POST, then what does your input file look like? is each line a URL then the query params? Or would it look like a GET request, and the query params should instead be part of the POST body? You **can** POST w/ curl, but the invocation is different, and how to do it depends on how you specify the POST params for each request

Comment: It's a post, each url has the needed params

Comment: Actually looks like I do have the option to use an HTTP GET URL which uses the REST communication model and I'll get a JSON response in return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make this with bash, but you can try to get these responses with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)